# JQuery fails to set the correct value of select

Tags: jquery

This is the markup:

```
<select id="fontsize">
    <option value="8pt">8pt</option>
    <option value="10pt">10pt</option>
    <option value="12pt">12pt</option>
    <option value="14pt">14pt</option>
    <option value="18pt">18pt</option>
    <option value="24pt">24pt</option>
    <option value="36pt">36pt</option>
</select>
```

and I have this in `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // init
    $('#fontsize').val(font_size);
    ...
});
```

and fontsize is a global variable set to '14pt'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var font_size = '14pt';
...
```

but when the page is viewed, the select shows the first option ('8pt'). In firebug console the same instruction, `$('#fontsize').val(font_size);`, successfully changes the select; why is is failing in `ready`?

Live page [here](http://jqeedu.tuxfamily.org/speed_read/do_practice.php?file=3.txt).
**Link updated**

Comment: unfortunately there is no `m.m` domain ..

Comment: Everything appears to be working http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/YpY8G/1/ could you post more of your script?  Any errors at all?

Comment: No errors. Link will be corrected in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "14pt" is set when you ask for it but the call to columnize seems to reinit all elements (use Firebug breakpoints to see code execution step by step). Trying to call columnize() before seems to fix the problem.

```
$('#ipsum').columnize({columns:nc}); 
$('#fontsize').val(font_size);
set_style();
```